Complex sequence $a_{n+1} = \sin (a_n)$
Consider a sequence $\{ a_n \}$ in $\mathbb C$, satisfying
$$a_{n+1} = \sin (a_n), a_0 \in \mathbb C.$$
I am wondering when the sequence converges.
If $a_0 \in \mathbb R$, it is easy to see that $\{ a_n \}$  converges to zero.
If $a_0 = i y$ for some non-zero $y \in \mathbb R$, then
$$a_n = i \sinh(\sinh( \cdots (y) \cdots ))$$
and so  $\{ a_n \}$  diverges.
My naive guess is:

$\{ a_n \}$  converges  if and only if $a_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Is it true?

If $a_0 = i$, then $a_1 = e^{-1}-e$, which then converges because it is real. Hence, ${a_n}$ has to converge for at least an uncountable amount of $a_0 \in \mathbb{C} \mathbb{R}$

@Nic, isn't it $a_1=i\sinh(1)$? In general, if $a_0 = yi$ for $y \in \mathbb R$, $a_n = i \sinh(\sinh( \cdots (y) \cdots ))$. This has been added to the question.

$$a_0=yi,y\in\mathbb R \implies a_n = i\sinh(\sinh( \cdots (y) \cdots )).$$

See this reference https://www.dynamics.unam.edu/DinamicaNoLineal/Articulos/Articulo18.pdf Page 2872

@Basics yes I forgot to divide by $2i$. Whoops!

@Brian Moehring, thanks for pointing out this. Now I realized that the issue is much more complicated than I originally thought.

There are a lot of examples of $a_0 \not\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $k>0$, each of which is a counterexample to your proposed guess.
For instance, when $a_0 = \frac{2n+1}2\pi + ri$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}^*$, then $a_0 \not\in \mathbb{R}$ but $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.
Further, since $\sin : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is surjective, there are also $a_0$ such that $a_1 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ and $a_2\in\mathbb{R}$.  Inductively, there are many values of $a_0$ such that $a_{k-1} \not\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $k$.

In a sense, the subset described above (of all $a_0$ such that $a_k \in\mathbb{R}$ eventually) is trivial set.  It's not clear to me whether this is the entire set of $a_0$ such that the sequence converges.
